# Summernote image upload gives an SQL error

Tags: laravel, summernote

I am stuck with a problem containing Summernote. I added the Summernote bar to my div, all functions work except the image uploader. It allows the image to be uploaded but when I click save. This error shows up:

> SQLSTATE[22001]: String data, right truncated: 1406 Data too long for column 'description' at row 1 (SQL: update `tasks` set `updated_at` = 2018-11-20 09:08:43

Does someone know how to resolve this problem? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

**First option:**

You can make `description` column type `text` without length.

**Second option:**

By default summernote insert image data to src. You can reduce data length, by upload images to server and insert image url instead of image data.

```
$('.summernote').summernot({
    callbacks: {
        onImageUpload: function(image, editor) {
            let data = new FormData();
            data.append('file', image[0]);
            $.ajax({
                url: 'path to your upload method',
                cache: false,
                contentType: false,
                processData: false,
                data: data,
                type: 'post',
                success: function (url) {
                    editor.summernote('insertImage', url);
                }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Change `description` column type to `TEXT`. if that is allready `TEXT` then change it to `MEDIUMTEXT`.

Remember length of `TEXT` type is 65,635 character only.

Use `MEDIUMTEXT` or `LONGTEXT` for big content.